# Fail to update apk when updating from titanium app to Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk, titanium, android-manifest

I have recently built an already existing app from ground up using the Android SDK. The previous version was a titanium mobile app, I have used the same keystore as the titanium app. The difference is that I have removed all `uses-feature`which was unnecessary but automatically generated in titanium.

When I upload the apk I get an error from the developer console which I find quite cryptic and I can't update the apk. I'm guessing this has something to do with titanium building the app with the NDK which I have no experience of.

Error:

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
>   It is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels in range 8-19 to API levels in range 20+ should downgrade from version 10 to version 3, which would occur when 
>   Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
>   Native platforms containing any of [armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86] and 
>   Features containing all of [android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.location.GPS, android.hardware.location.NETWORK, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, android.hardware.WIFI].

Titanium manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><manifest android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.3" package="xx.xxx.xxx" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/><uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

<!-- TI_MANIFEST -->

<application android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="xxxxxx" android:name="xxxxxx">

    <!-- TI_APPLICATION -->

    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:label="XXXXXX" android:name=".XXXXX" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiModalActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity"/>

    <service android:exported="false" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.analytics.TiAnalyticsService"/>


</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

New SDK Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xxx.xxx.xxx" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/details"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
</application>
```

EDIT: the new app is built using Android Studio, and the rest of the declarations are in gradle where Versioncode is : 10 and minSDK is 8

Answer (score 0):

You have no android:versionCode in your new Manifest.xml.

Comment: Read bottom Edit, versionCode is injected by gradle

Comment: Have you checked that Android Studio actually injects it correctly. You can check by doing: aapt dump badging  dinapp.apk|grep versionCode

Comment: versionCode 10 , I'm guessing that it wants to downgrade because the NDK specifically says which platforms are optimized for which version.